# LWC Cannot call a public method in child component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, api, salesforce-classic

We're having issues calling a public (`@api`) method in child component from the parent. We are doing everything as in the guides - the child has an annotated method:

```js
@api publicMethod(param) {
    console.log('--------public method in child called with param:', param);
}
```

The parent calls the method as follows (button click handler):

```js
let child = this.template.querySelector('c-lwc-asset-group-list');
child.publicMethod({a:'param'});
```

The error we get is

> Uncaught TypeError: `this.template.querySelector(...).publicMethod` is not a function

I couldn't find a similar issue when I was looking for a solution.

Edit: The parent component is created inside a Visulaforce page, not sure if this is relevant.

Edit 2: The error message does not display in the dev console, but rather at the bottom of the page in a `div#auraErrorMessge`.

Edit 3: The problem seems to be in `this.template.querySelector`, because when called on a regular class inside the template's DOM, e.g. like this:

`this.template.querySelector('.top-container').scrollIntoView(true);`,

we get the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `this.template.querySelector(...).scrollIntoView` is not a function.

Comment: Have you tried using Pubsub? https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub

Comment: What happens when you attempt this without the VF page? Does it work? It would help to see a bit more of the details of lwcAssetGroupList. One possible issue could be the camel-case-to-kebab-case name conversion goofing up the `querySelector` call.

Comment: @pchittum I probably should have expressed myself better. Both parent and child are LWCs. The parent is initialized from a VF page. We are not running in Lightning Experience. I could try switching to it and adding the parent to a tab... But I don't think it would matter. EDIT: But it won't be a very easy task, the parent has some api parameters as well, so I will first need to make a wrapper component.

Comment: So when you say the parent is initialized from a VF page, how are you doing that? Are you using lightning for Visualforce? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it, the way it is in your link.

Comment: So using the component in regular Lightning Experience is nearly impossible, because it is designed to run in Partner Community and requires a Partner Community user. I tried putting it on the Home tab, but exceptions were thrown from Apex controllers before the component got anywhere.

Comment: Ah...sorry, I assumed the component was for LEX...what about using it directly in Partner Community with no visualforce?

Comment: so the problem seems to be in `this.template.querySelector`, because when called on a regular class inside the template's DOM, e.g. like this: `this.template.querySelector('.top-container').scrollIntoView(true);`, we get the same error: 

`Uncaught TypeError: this.template.querySelector(...).scrollIntoView is not a function.`
Any ideas @pchittum?

Comment: What does it say in the console if you put a `console.log(typeof this.template.querySelector);` in the function?

Comment: it says `function`